# Who is the brewer at the end of Lovecraft's Celephais?

Tags: character-identification, celephais

Spoiler alert:

> "Though below the cliffs at Innsmouth the channel tides played mockingly with the body of a tramp who had stumbled through the half-deserted village at dawn; played mockingly, and cast it upon the rocks by ivy-covered Trevor Towers, where a notably fat and especially offensive millionaire brewer enjoys the purchased atmosphere of extinct nobility."

Was the millionaire brewer a reference to someone I'm supposed to know? I've read the Shadow Over Innsmouth but I don't recognize him. I'm guessing the "purchased atmosphere" is opiates but what was the significance of this character in the story?

Comment: I doubt that the “purchased atmosphere” is opiates, but rather refers to a newly rich person enjoying the luxury of old money.

Comment: Nice question -- I seem to recall (probably from some of Lovecraft's correspondence) that this was Kuranes actual family home / seat, that had been purchased by someone nouveau riche attempting to gain the respectability of the old families by purchasing the trappings and lands they once owned.  Hence the added irony/poignancy of him washing up there, at the bottom of things in the real world, while having ascended to the top, in the Dream Realm.  It wouldn't surprise me for it to have a REAL, real-world correspondence, but I have no backup for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### No one special

The key word here is "Trevor Towers." According to "The Dream-Quest of Unknown Kadath," this is where Kuranes, who appears both here and in *Celephais*, was born.

> There he dwelt in a grey Gothic manor-house of stone looking on the
> sea, and tried to think it was ancient Trevor Towers, where he was
> born and where thirteen generations of his forefathers had first seen
> the light.
>
> <sub>“The Dream-Quest of Unknown Kadath”</sub>

The reference to “thirteen generations” (perhaps roughly 250 years) suggests that his family were “old money.”

Thus the reference to a millionaire brewer is not about anyone in particular, but about the purchase of an old, basically noble estate by an uncouth upstart parvenu. The contrast is between the stately manor-house and the repulsive businessperson who now owns it. The “atmosphere of extinct nobility” is exactly what it sounds like, and not opiates.

While the specificity of the language might lead us to believe that this is a recurring character, it would seem that he is merely an archetype.

Answer (score 1):

The brewer represents the "nouveau riche", or "new money" - a class of people that have risen to high social status through amassing wealth, and used that wealth to purchase the trappings of nobility and aristocracy. The main character of the story is *actual* aristocracy; it is his body that washes up under the tower - his own ancestral home.